# Generating table schema from entities

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am using Skipper ORM to design/generate entities - everything exports fine - then I do:

```
app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
app/console doctrine:database:create
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
app/console doctrine:generate:entities --no-backup MyNamespace/MyBundle
```

I am receiving an error/exception:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
>   There is no column with name 'alternateId' on table 'inventory'.

What gives? The entity in question certainly does have the field:

```
<?php
namespace Company\DistributionBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\DistributionBundle\Repository\InventoryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="inventory",
 *     indexes={@ORM\Index(name="ALTID", columns={"alternateId"})},
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="PKID", columns={"id"}),
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="FINDID", columns={"partNumber","partDescription"})
 *     }
 * )
 */
class Inventory
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $alternateId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $unitOftMeasure;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $minimumQuantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $maximumQuantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=false)
     */
    private $maximumCycles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=false, precision=10, scale=4)
     */
    private $maximumTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=false, precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $listPrice;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $datePrice;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $partNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $partDescription;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $partNotes;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company\DistributionBundle\Entity\Application", inversedBy="inventory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="application_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $application;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company\DistributionBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="inventory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company\DistributionBundle\Entity\Manufacturer", inversedBy="inventory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $manufacturer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company\DistributionBundle\Entity\InventoryOptions", mappedBy="inventory")
     */
    private $inventoryOptions;
}
```

Comment: When I drop the indexes on inventory it seems to work?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [doctrine migrations bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) for two reasons:

1. It helps you manage your production database and all the versions of it. You can check any version any time
2. It Beautifully creates 'sql migrations' for you. Which you can use to (run migrations) to make changes in database.

Also, it understand your entities, read the annotations and creates the required files.

Go ahead and explore it.

Comment: I will start with migrations soon...the problem was due to table names having underscore instead of camelcase...explicitly naming columns solved problems.